# Permutations groups and symmetric groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Does there exit a solution of equation $x^2=(1234)$ in $S_4$ Group?

In solution of this question the reason state that no because $x^2$ is odd permutations which is not possible for $S_4$ . So I try to make a general statement for this

“ Does $x^2$ equals to odd permutations have solutions in any symmetric group $S_n$.“

My answer is no because irrespective of what type of permutations $x$ is $x^2$ must be even Permutations . Also I have verified it for $S_4$ but still I am not completely certain about this statement.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask.  Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I think the question is about whether $\{x^2 | x \in S_n\}=A_n$, which is an interesting one, but we'll have to wait till the poster clarifies.

Comment: But then the first sentence of the second paragraph does not make much sense. The poster should consider $(1,2)(3,4,5,6) \in S_6$.

Comment: @Adesh Sharma Have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240823/even-permutation-in-sn

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3027100/589